# Server doesn't recv and send message

Tags: python

I am trying to build a server and client with threading so that the server has two threading recv and send and also the client. But my problem is that I don't know why my server prints a send and recv error.

My server

```
from threading import Thread
import socket

global recv_msg
global connect


def socket_connect():
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8350))
        print "Server start"
        sock.listen(1)
        connect, addr = sock.accept()
        print "Client Ip: " + str(addr[0])
    except socket.error:
        print "Server error"


def send_to_client():
    try:
        connect.send("Server:" + recv_msg + "\n")
    except:
        print "Error send"


def recv_from_client():
    try:
        recv_msg = connect.recv(1024)
    except:
        print "Error Recv"


def main():
    while True:
        recv_thread = Thread(target=recv_from_client, )
        send_thread = Thread(target=send_to_client,)

        recv_thread.start()
        send_thread.start()

        recv_thread.join()
        send_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My client

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    client_socket.connect(("89.139.105.181", 8350))
    print "Client connection success"
except socket.error:
    print "Client error"


def send_to_server():
    msg = raw_input("Client:")
    client_socket.send(msg)


def recv_from_server():
    response_server = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print response_server


def main():
    while True:
        send_thread = Thread(target=send_to_server,)
        recv_thread = Thread(target=recv_from_server,)

        send_thread.start()
        recv_thread.start()

        send_thread.join()
        recv_thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where could the error be coming from?

Comment: Never use `except:` without specifying the exact exception you want to catch. Otherwise, all exceptions are caught, and you cannot know what went wrong. And that's exactly what is happening: there are blatant mistakes in your code, but the error messages are hidden by your catch-all `except:`.

Comment: What can I do ? Please explain more in order to solve my problem

Comment: He's saying you shouldn't use `Except: print('somethings wrong')` but rather do `Except KeyboardInterrupt: print('You pressed Ctrl-C')` for instance. Also, what does your actual error messages say (when removing the `try:` around everything`? We have no error output to work on here. My assumption is that the Thread can't use `connect` even tho you tried to make it global. but that's just a glanced overview of the problem.

Comment: Use something like: `except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]`

Comment: Also what OS are you on?

Comment: @stark Windows 10